# Notation: how to unzip a set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I have a set of triple $S_z=\{(x_1,y_2,z),(x_2,y_2,z),(x_3,y_1,z),\ldots\}$ where the last element of each triple is the same.

I want to create the set $S=\{x_1,y_2,x_2,x_3,y_1\}$ of all elements of $S_z$ not including $z$. What is the notation used to do this?

Something like $$S=\{i \text{ or } j: (i,j,z)\in S_z\}?$$

Comment: I would use $\{x~:~x = i \vee x=j,~(i,j,z)\in S_z\}$ or something similar.  That said, words are sometimes preferable to notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go for:$$S=\left\{ u\mid\exists\left(a,b,c\right)\in S_{z}\left[u\in\left\{ a,b\right\} \right]\right\} $$

Answer (score 2):

Consider two projection maps defined on the set $S_z$:

$pr_1 ((x,y,z))=x$ and $pr_2 ((x,y,z))=y$.

Then 
$$
S=Im( pr_1) \cup Im( pr_2).
$$

Comment: This would be my solution as well, but I’d write $\operatorname{pr}_1(S_z)$ instead of $\operatorname{Im}(\operatorname{pr}_1)$. This way, the projection does not need to depend on $z$ which seems somewhat unnatural to me.

Answer (score 1):

$$\{x\mid(x,y,z)\in S_z\}\cup\{y\mid(x,y,z)\in S_z\}$$